# Java Brick Breaker Game - "array required, but java.util.List found"

Tags: java

I am having a little bit of an issue with my brick breaker coursework game.
I am trying to make the game produce bricks by using an array however I have ran into a little bit of an error of "array required, but java.util.List found".

Can anyone help?

Class that I am having trouble with:

```
public void createGameObjects()
{
 synchronized( Model.class )
 {
   ball   = new GameObj(W/2, H/2, BALL_SIZE, BALL_SIZE, Colour.RED );
   bat    = new GameObj(W/2, H - BRICK_HEIGHT*1.5f, BRICK_WIDTH*3, 
                                   BRICK_HEIGHT/4, Colour.GRAY);
   bricks = new ArrayList<>();
   bricks[0] = new GameObj(0,0, BRICK_HEIGHT, BRICK_WIDTH, Colour.BLUE);
 }
}
```

The error is occurring on the bottom line:

```
bricks[0] = new GameObj(0,0, BRICK_HEIGHT, BRICK_WIDTH, Colour.BLUE);
```

Thank you

Comment: You're using ArrayList object bricks in array[] form which is wrong, for ArrayList you can use bricks.add(new GameObj(--,---,--));

Comment: An `ArrayList` is not an array, but you try to use `bricks` as an array.

Comment: Please don't mutilate posts. If you want to be disassociated from a post, flag for moderator attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are delaring `bricks` as an `ArrayList` and trying to access the elements in `array` way, hence the error. Try changing the below:

```
bricks = new ArrayList<>();
bricks[0] = new GameObj(0,0, BRICK_HEIGHT, BRICK_WIDTH, Colour.BLUE);
```

to

```
bricks = new ArrayList<>();
bricks.add(new GameObj(0,0, BRICK_HEIGHT, BRICK_WIDTH, Colour.BLUE));
```

This will add the element in the `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thank you that has done the job. I was just having one of those blank moments!

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `List` elements using `[index]` (array syantax), rather use `add` method and assuming that you are loading single `Game` object into the `ArrayList<Game>`, you need to add to the `bricks` `List` as shown below:

```
ArrayList<Game> bricks = new ArrayList<>();
bricks.addd(new GameObj(0,0, BRICK_HEIGHT, BRICK_WIDTH, Colour.BLUE));
```